# How to include a javascript file if you don't have access to the head tag

Tags: javascript, html, include

I am using a web framework where I have the ability to add javascript to the page, but I don't have the ability to add content to the head tag. Am I still able to include a new javascript include file dynamically? What javascript code should I use? I also don't have jquery and would like to use internet explorer 8 only.

Comment: can you not just copy the content of the js-file into the framework?

Comment: `meta` tag? I would use `script` like `<script>alert("Hello world!");</script>`

Comment: There's a limit on the size of the javascript I can inject. So I would like to be able to dynamically include.

Comment: I suppose he meant the head-tag

Comment: You can put `<script>` tags in the `body` too, where is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have `script` elements inside `body` just as inside `head`, so if you can inject anything into the document, you can inject

```
<script src=foobar.js></script>
```

Comment: I did not think of that! If you can insert HTML into the content of the site, this would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link: http://javascript.about.com/library/bladdjs.htm

It is possible to add a script-tag to the head without using jQuery:

```
var th = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
s.setAttribute('src','PATH/TO/SCRIPT.js');
th.appendChild(s);
```